# Work with foreign key

Tags: c#, sql-server

In my application has been conflicts with the primary key constraint and a foreign key. I use stored procedures in a programming language c # and SqlDataReader. How to add data to the foreign keys in the database, that there was not primary key constraint. As the example of a way to organize this?

That my code for firstTable:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(STORED_PREFIX + STORED_NAME2, connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@io", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@io"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
cmd.Parameters["@io"].Value = 1;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@idstud", SqlDbType.BigInt);
cmd.Parameters["@idstud"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
cmd.Parameters["@idstud"].Value = id_studtextBox.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@numb_stud", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@numb_stud"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
cmd.Parameters["@numb_stud"].Value = numberstudtextbox.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@naim_corpus", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
cmd.Parameters["@naim_corpus"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
cmd.Parameters["@naim_corpus"].Value = naimcorpuscombobox.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@place", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@place"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
cmd.Parameters["@place"].Value = placetextbox.Text;
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read())
{
    dataGridView2.Rows.Add((string)rdr[_id_stud].ToString(), 
      (string)rdr[_nomer_stud].ToString(),
      (string)rdr[_naim_corpus].ToString(),
      (string)rdr[_mesto].ToString());
}
```

That code for secondTable

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(STORED_PREFIX + STORED_NAME2, connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@daw", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@daw"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
cmd.Parameters["@daw"].Value = 3;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@teachid", SqlDbType.BigInt);
cmd.Parameters["@teachid"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
cmd.Parameters["@teachid"].Value = id_cabtextBox.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@numb_teacher", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@numb_teacher"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
cmd.Parameters["@numb_teacher"].Value = numbercabtextbox.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@naim_corpus", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
cmd.Parameters["@naim_corpus"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
cmd.Parameters["@naim_corpus"].Value = naimcorpuscombobox.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@studid", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@studid"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
cmd.Parameters["@studid"].Value = studidtextbox.Text;
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read())
{
    dataGridView2.Rows.Add((string)rdr[_teacher_id].ToString(),
     (string)rdr[_nomer_teacher].ToString(),
     (string)rdr[_naim_corpus].ToString(),
     (string)rdr[_studid].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Can you try to explain your question in more detail. I do not undertsand what you are asking.

Comment: I want use combobox list with saved data in another table without dataadapter, bindingsource.

Comment: Where error in code?         `code 
                cabcomboBox.Items.Add(new valuecombobox((rdr[_fk_cab]),(rdr[_nomer_cab]).ToString()));`

Comment: Sorry I do not undertsand, if you can speak russian, you can try http://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Where error in code? `code cabcomboBox.Items.Add(new valuecombobox((rdr[_fk_cab]),(rdr[_nomer_cab]).ToString()));` it has some invalid arguments

Comment: What error message are you getting? Are _fk_cab and _nomer_cab variables? Do you set their values somewhere?

Comment: _fk_cab - integer and _nomer_cab - integer variable,  i created class for to view values in combobox one's not visible _fk_cab, and the other is visible  _nomer_cab. The most appropriate method for the overloaded "Monitoring_of_computer_equipments.valuecombobox.valuecombobox (int, string)" has some invalid arguments

Comment: Try cabcomboBox.Items.Add(new valuecombobox((rdr.GetInt32(_fk_cab)),(rdr[_nomer_cab]).ToString())); See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3 for more details